# Is there a way to discover why IndexedDB is dropped?

Tags: android, google-chrome, local-storage, indexeddb, web-storage

I am developing web application for mobile which utilises IndexedDB to store values.
I visited the website using my phone, and come back after a while and IndexedDB data is still there.
But, sometimes it totally is lost. I don't know why. I looked online for solution they said phone storage low will sometimes clear, I have 100GB/128GB used which is 28GB free, and even SD card external, so I don't think that is problem. Online other solution said that cleaner software such like Cleaner 360 can clear IndexedDB from Chrome browser app data, but my phone is not installed any types of these cleaning software.
I want to find out the reason why this IndexedDB is clearing, and is affecting my web application.

I try to check all the phone storage, and everything looks okay, even I try to display value of when IndexedDB is created in website, so I make sure it's not my retriving code problem and actually IndexedDB is cleared. Even I checked Chrome browser version is up to date on app store. Or any friends have alternative solution to store data?